# Jenkins script console: how to start a build for a job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

From jenkins script console, how can I initiate a build for a job?

**Tried:**

```
    for(job in Hudson.instance.getView(view_name).items) {
    job.startBuild()
}
```

**Error:**
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.startBuild() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Answer (score 0):

You can use `run.scheduleBuild`, as [example](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=43089972#content/view/43089972)

> ```
>  cause = new hudson.model.Cause.RemoteCause(startServer, startNote)
>  failedRuns.each{run -> run.scheduleBuild(cause)}
> ```